# Interpretation of Sequential (Serial) Mediation Effect (vs. Cross-lagged panel model)

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, mediation, path-model

[image: Serial Mediation]

I would like some clarification on the interpretation of the significant indirect effect involving "d21", when the two mediators (M1, M2) are the same constructs measured at two consecutive time points.

(1) How would you explain a scenario where only the indirect effect involving d21 is significant (and M1 and M2 alone do not show significant indirect effects)?

(2) Can you conclude that significant d21 reflects the importance of the "change of M between time 1 and time 2", as you would in a cross-lagged panel analysis? (whereas different M1 and M2 constructs typically involve explanations like, "x predicted M1, which in turn predicted M2" or "the shared influence of M1 and M2 mediated the pathway between x and y")

(3) When a residualized change score of M1-M2 is used as a single mediator of X->Y, there is no significant indirect effect. What is the statistical difference between the two models that would explain this discrepancy?